# Slice pandas rows between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to slice a Pandas dataframe according to values in a couple of pandas series.
So I need the rows in-between the values of the pandas series.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns = list('abcde'))
```

[image]

```
df_info = pd.DataFrame(data= {'beginRows': [2, 7], 'endRows': [4, 9]}
```

[image]

I need the rows in df that are between the value of beginRows and endRows, in each row of df_info.
Technically, I can do this as:

```
df_result = df[df.index.isin(np.r_[2:4+1,7:9+1])]
```

[image]

I am not sure how to make that list to send as a parameter to np.r_, from the df_info dataframe.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI - df_info is a large dataframe, and it would be unrealistic to write it out manually into the parameters of np.r_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) objects:

```
slice1 = slice(2, 4+1)
slice2 = slice(7, 9+1)

df_result = df[df.index.isin(np.r_[slice1, slice2])]
```

Given your input `df_info`:

```
s1, s2 = [slice(i, j+1) for i, j in df_info.values]

df_result = df[df.index.isin(np.r_[s1, s2])]
```

Or, for an arbitrary number of slices, you can pass a `tuple` to `np.r_.__getitem__`:

```
slices = tuple(slice(i, j+1) for i, j in df_info.values)

df_result = df[df.index.isin(np.r_.__getitem__(slices))]
```

Comment: Note: df_info could be bigger than 2 rows, so just make that a list. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - the tuple is way faster! Appreciate it!